# Is there any way to log LDAP queries in Windows without debug feature?

Tags: windows, logging, active-directory, ldap

If there are any way to log LDAP queries in Windows without turning on debug mode via regedit? To be more specific, I'm curious if there are mechanisms (callbacks or something like that) which can be used to subscribe on LDAP server events and have access to LDAP query it receives?

I've tried to use diagnostic event logging that Microsoft offers to see LDAP queries, but it collects all events and consumes a lot of DC's resources. In case I need only specific events (specific queries) - this is not really efficient. Probably, there is a solution to filter queries on the fly?